# Adding jury membres in Beamer Presentation

Tags: beamer, titles, presentations

I am preparing a presentation in LaTex using Beamer and I want to add information like the jury members, so I tried and I get this :

Here is My MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\usefonttheme[]{serif}
\usepackage{amsmath, latexsym, color, graphicx, amssymb, bm, here}
\usepackage{epsf, epsfig, pifont,tikz,subfigure}
\usepackage{graphics, calrsfs}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{fancybox,calc}
\usepackage{palatino,mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\titlegraphicii[1]{\def\inserttitlegraphicii{#1}}
\titlegraphicii{}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
  \vbox{}
   {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\hfill\inserttitlegraphicii\par}
  \begin{centering}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}%\vskip0.5em
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{centering}
  %\vfill
}
\makeatother
\author{Presented by Author}
\title{Presentation Title}
\subtitle{Presentation Subtile}
\institute{Department \\ University}
\date{\today}


\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\maketitle
\small
{\centering\itshape Jury Members\par}
President: president\par\medskip
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\hspace{3pt}}p{.32\textwidth}@{}}
Examiners: & examiner 1 \\
& examiner 2 \\
& examiner 3 \\
& examiner 4
\end{tabular}%
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\hspace{3pt}}p{.3\textwidth}@{}}
Supervisor 1: & supervisor \\
Supervisor 2: & supervisor
\end{tabular}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Which gives this result:
[image]

And I want something like this : [image]

Could you please help me?

Comment: If the difference is the top bar with sections, you have to insert sections in your presentation that after two compilations will start to appear on top of title page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The option `[plain]` suppresses the headline on your title page. If you remove this option, you'll get the headline back.

Off-topic, Off-topic, but you don't need `graphicx`, `graphics` or `color` with beamer, as beamer already provides this functionality. And as Mike Renfro pointed out [in his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397617/adding-jury-membres-in-beamer-presentation/397619?noredirect=1#comment989459_397619) `epsf` and `epsfig` are deprecated for some time now.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\usefonttheme[]{serif}
\usepackage{amsmath, latexsym,
%, color, graphicx, 
amssymb, bm, here}
\usepackage{
%epsf, epsfig, 
pifont,tikz,subfigure}
\usepackage{
%graphics, 
calrsfs}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{fancybox,calc}
\usepackage{palatino,mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\titlegraphicii[1]{\def\inserttitlegraphicii{#1}}
\titlegraphicii{}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
  \vbox{}
   {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\hfill\inserttitlegraphicii\par}
  \begin{centering}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}%\vskip0.5em
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{centering}
  %\vfill
}
\makeatother
\author{Presented by Author}
\title{Presentation Title}
\subtitle{Presentation Subtile}
\institute{Department \\ University}
\date{\today}


\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\small
{\centering\itshape Jury Members\par}
President: president\par\medskip
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\hspace{3pt}}p{.32\textwidth}@{}}
Examiners: & examiner 1 \\
& examiner 2 \\
& examiner 3 \\
& examiner 4
\end{tabular}%
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\hspace{3pt}}p{.3\textwidth}@{}}
Supervisor 1: & supervisor \\
Supervisor 2: & supervisor
\end{tabular}%
\end{frame}

\section{test}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `epsf` and `epsfig` are also deprecated for some time now.

Comment: @MikeRenfro Thanks for spotting! I added you comment to the answer.

Comment: Hello everyone! Is there a way to center the two columns below "Jury Members"?